# Running Difference Per Account Per Date

Tags: mysql

```
account  Debit_Balance    Long       Short      Date         Daily_Change (Expected) 
716-05    18981100       27946000   8964860   4/10/2018         0
716-06    -7526070       1676250    9202320   4/10/2018         0
716-07    6596930        26579600   19982700  4/10/2018         0
716-11    -1555190       3298790    4853980   4/10/2018         0
716-05    12861700       20754400   7892750   4/11/2018       -6119400
716-06    -8717010       1585470    10302500  4/11/2018       -1190940
716-07    7900390        28052300   20151900  4/11/2018       1303460
716-11   -1641360        3482290    5123650   4/11/2018       -86170
```

I need to create the column above "Daily_Change" which would be the daily difference of Debit_Balance per account. So the account 716-05's Debit_Balance for 4/11/2018 minus 716-05's Debit_Balance for 4/10/2018. There are about thirty accounts total over the span of about a month.

The query I am currently using:

```
select account, balance as Debit_Balance, int_balance as "Long", 
short_mkt_value as Short, report_date as Date
from table
where group_name = "Carter"
and report_date in
(
select report_date
from table
group by report_date
order by account asc)
order by report_date asc, account asc
```

Comment: The only thing you needed to do with that answer is add an extra condition on join.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following

```
SELECT t1.*,t1.balance-t2.balance Daily_Change
FROM TestData t1
LEFT JOIN TestData t2
ON t2.report_date=DATE_SUB(t1.report_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
  AND t1.account=t2.account
ORDER BY t1.report_date,t1.account
```

SQL Fiddle - http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/033d7b/10

Comment: I'm sorry this was correct, my mistake. Thanks again.

Comment: OK. :) Good luck!